# No portable class library folder found in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am a newbie working with Xamarin Forms in Visual studio 2019.

When I create a blank page for **Mobile App(Xamarin.Forms)** , I do not see a Xamarin.forms portable template app in my project solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no PCL anymore. PCL is outdated. Just use the Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms) template. It will create all you need.

The core project (that contains your shared code) will be a .net standard project.
.net standard is way better than PCL, because you don't have a artificially limited set of APIs.

[image]

this creates the following 3 projects

[image]

Your shared code should go into the App8 project

[image]

Comment: I have only .android and .ios folders created. But where do we write the "shared" code?

Comment: it creates 3 projects. 1) MyApp 2) MyApp.Android 3) MyApp.iOS. The MyApp project should contain the shared code. I updated my answer.

Comment: yeah i was expecting this, but only 2 folders are created(myapp.android and myapp.ios). Is there any installations that I have missed while installing visual studio

Comment: Hmm that's odd. Usually if you install the Xamarin / mobile development package, everything you need is installed. Is you VS up to date?

Comment: Might be, re-installed visual studio and its fine now