# Xamari, dont recognize all the projects

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

When I create a Xamarin mobile app, I just noticed that I don't have the main project, just like in the photo.

[The way i see the projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFheA.png)

[Main Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTMCw.png)

Did you know why it's happening? I tried repairing it, but it didn't work. Then I just installed some Hyper-V, but it didn't work either

Comment: Please stop abusing tags that are irellevant to your question. VS not loading projects has nothing to do with bios or hyper-v.

Answer (score 0):

> When I create a Xamarin mobile app, I just noticed that I don't have the main project...

This is caused by Visual Studio. Updating or reinstalling VS should solve this failure.

Similar situation, refer to this case: [No portable class library folder found in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59455062/no-portable-class-library-folder-found-in-xamarin-forms).